# Get all posts that have a custom field value with meta key and loop the query results from another field value

Tags: php, wordpress, function, loops, foreach

how can i get all posts of both custom post type 'folder' and  'file' that have the same custom field value in custom field 'wpcf-secret-id-1' and in case if there are results i would like to show the value of another custom field 'wpcf-secret-id-2'.

I have tried following code but seems not to work:

```html
function get_all_post_from_field_value($postid)
{
    $args  = array(
        'post_type' => array(
            'folder', 'file'
        ),
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'wpcf-secret-id-1',
                'value' => ( $postid )
            )
        )
    );
    // The Query
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    // The Loop
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            // I am not sure how to get the field value of 'wpcf-secret-id-2'
            return get_post_field('wpcf-secret-id-2');
        }
    }
  
}
add_shortcode( 'get-posts-by-field-value', 'get_all_post_from_field_value');
```

I would like at the end to get all posts where first custom field value is the same of current post and show the results as a loop of the second custom field value

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it should work, I don't see anything obviously wrong with your query.

The only thing that may be happening is: are these custom fields hidden? Have you looked in your post_meta table in your database to check the correct key to be querying for `wpcf-secret-id-1` and `wpcf-secret-id-2`? If they are hidden from the backend, they may have an underscore prepended like this: `_wpcf-secret-id-1`.

Also, your WP_Query usage isnt correct in this case. You are overriding the entire Wordpress Loop with `$query->the_post();` and are returning out of the function before resetting it with [wp_reset_postdata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata).

A better way to do that would be:

```
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->found_posts > 0) {

    $post = $query->posts[0];
    return get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-secret-id-2', true);
}
else
{
   return ""; //Good habit: if you are returning some value, make sure you always return *something*, even when there is no value to return.
}
```